# Import scss doesn´t work for media queries

Tags: css, import, sass

I am trying to import my media queries from a other file in the same directory but it doesn´t work but when I put the media queries inside the same file (style.scss) it works

**style.scss**

@import '_responsive';

**_responsive.scss**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1230px) { 
    .section01-header {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try it without the _ in front of it. Like @import "variables". Make sure they are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example hope you will get point its helpful for you...

you must remove _ before calling element in parent folder or file. you need to
write simple like ex: @import 'responsive'

To more understand please check this url:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sky-p8zlg?file=/index.html